# Is there a simple way to readlines from text file to this beautiful soup lib python script?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, text-files, readline

How can I read lines from a txt.file into this script instead of having to list urls inside the script? Thank you

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://www.url1.com"

response = requests.get(url)

data = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

categories = soup.find_all("a", {"class":'navlabellink nvoffset nnormal'})

for category in categories:
    print(url + "," + category.text)
```

My text.file contents have a separator of a newline:

```
http://www.url1.com
http://www.url2.com
http://www.url3.com
http://www.url4.com
http://www.url5.com
http://www.url6.com
http://www.url7.com
http://www.url8.com
http://www.url9.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read URLs from `a.txt`, you can use this script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open('a.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        if not line:
            continue

        response = requests.get(line)
        data = response.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
        categories = soup.find_all("a", {"class":'navlabellink nvoffset nnormal'})

        for category in categories:
            print(url + "," + category.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
file1 = open('text.file', 'r') 
Lines = file1.readlines() 

count = 0
# Strips the newline character 
for line in Lines: 
    print("Line{}: {}".format(count, line.strip()))
```

and you just replace your line by url variable

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of this example, let's say that your file is named `urls.txt`. In Python, it is very easy to open a file and read it's contents.

```
with open('urls.txt', 'r') as f:
    urls = f.read().splitlines()
#Your list of URLs is now in the urls list!
```

The `'r'` after `'urls.txt'` simply tells Python to just open the file in reading mode. If you don't need to modify a file, it is always best practice to open it in read-only mode. f.read() returns the entire contents of the file, but it contains newline characters (`\n`), so `splitlines()` will remove those characters and create a list for you.